# how to fix 'events.js:180 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: spawn ls ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm

I get the error:

> 'events.js:180 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: spawn ls
>   ENOENT

and tried to fix it using all relevant solutions in Stack Overflow, but I could not get it fixed...

Would you please guide me to a solution?

```
nmp init  

npm install

npm start

npm install express


const cp = require('child_process');

 var progs={
    list:"ls",
   copy:"cpy",
    folder:"mkdir"
 }
var child=cp.spawn(progs.list);
```

Comment: which operating system are you using? and This error is almost always caused because the command does not exist because the working directory does not exist or from a window bug.

Comment: Windows oprating system. i am using, then how can i fix it?